# Deserializing FileInfo doesn't work when in a self-made class

Tags: c#, winforms, constructor, json.net, abstract-class

I have a C# code where I'm using Newtonsoft to Serialize and Deserialize my class data to a .json file.
Previously I stored the FileInfo directly, which worked fine.
I now started using a 'wrapper' like object, because i wanted to adjust some behaviour.
I have a abstract CustomFile class, with a CustomNormalFile class implementing the CustomFile properties.
Because previously another error was related to the Deserializer not knowing what class to use, I set the Serializer to set the class types in the textfile.

Some further background info:
This is code in a Windows Forms application in C#.

I think it has to do with the Constructor of the CustomFile.
Therefore i have tried different versions of the constructor, and the simplified De/serialization of only one CustomFile (it is actually used in another class). Also i have used a constructor without parameters, or no constructor at all (so the 'default' constructor is made on compile time)
I have debugged it step by step, that didn't help me either, as the Deserialization doesn't show much.
I would say im a moderately experienced user, and want to do this the 'proper' way, instead of hacking it.
Thank you already for all the answers (hope we will find the issue)

The code that i think is relevant to the question, need more? tell me.
First the testcode where I de/serialize a CustomFile and a FileInfo:

```
// Serialize & Deserialize CustomFile
MusicAlbum album = collectionlossless.albums.ElementAt(1).Value;
CustomFile CustomCoverFile = album.covers.First();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings()
{
    TypeNameHandling = TypeNameHandling.Objects,
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
string temppathfile1 = "C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\tempCustomFile.js";
var current_cover_file = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(CustomCoverFile, settings);
File.WriteAllText(temppathfile1, current_cover_file);

string imp_cover_text = File.ReadAllText(temppathfile1);
CustomNormalFile imported_cover_file = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CustomNormalFile>(imp_cover_text, settings);

// Serialize & Deserialize FileInfo
FileInfo FileInfoCoverFile = new FileInfo(CustomCoverFile.FullPath);
string temppathfile2 = "C:\\Users\\username\\Downloads\\tempFileInfo.js";
var current_cover_fileinfo = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(FileInfoCoverFile, settings);
File.WriteAllText(temppathfile2, current_cover_fileinfo);

string imp_cover_text_info = File.ReadAllText(temppathfile2);
FileInfo imported_cover_fileinfo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<FileInfo>(imp_cover_text_info, settings);
// End debug steps
```

And now the class CustomFile and CustomNormalFile:

```
public abstract class CustomFile
{
    public abstract string Name { get; }
    public abstract string NameWithoutExtension { get; }
    public abstract string Extension { get; }
    public abstract string FullPath { get; }
    public abstract string DirectoryPath { get; }
    public abstract string DirectoryName { get; }
    public abstract bool Exists { get; }

    public abstract bool IsLocked();

    // File version from normal file
    public static CustomFile FromNormalFile(FileInfo file)
    {
        return new CustomNormalFile(file);
    }

    // File version from archive file
    public static CustomFile FromArchiveFile(FileInfo archive, ZipArchiveEntry entry)
    {
        return new CustomArchiveFile(archive, entry);
    }

    // File version from path (to normal file)
    public static CustomFile FromPath(string path)
    {
        return new CustomNormalFile(path);
    }
}
```

and:

```
public class CustomNormalFile : CustomFile
{
    FileInfo file;
    // Init with a function
    //public CustomNormalFile()
    //{

    //}
    public CustomNormalFile(FileInfo fileInfo)
    {
        if (fileInfo == null)
        {
            // somethings wrong
        }
        file = fileInfo;
    }

    [JsonConstructor]
    public CustomNormalFile(string path)
    {
        file = new FileInfo(path);
    }

    // Implement functions
    public override string Name
    { get { return file.Name; } }

    public override string Extension
    { get { return file.Extension; } }

    public override string FullPath
    { get { return file.FullName; } }

    public override string DirectoryPath
    { get { return file.Directory.Parent.FullName; } }

    public override string DirectoryName
    {
        get
        {
            return file.Directory.Name;
        }
    }

    public override string NameWithoutExtension
    { get { return Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file.Name); } }

    }
}
```

Comment: This may have to do with the fact there are no setters and no way to know where to put the deserialized value.

Comment: At the position of _"// somethings wrong"_ you'd should throw the [ArgumentNullException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.argumentnullexception?view=net-6.0)

Comment: @hijinxbassist, that indeed solved the problem, thanks! I've been searching quite a lot there.